# sql management studio failed to install

Tags: sql-server-2008

hi i have successfully installed the SQL SERVER 2008 express to my window 7 x 32bit from here
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b

But i do not find a way to install the SQLmanagement studio for 2008 express sql. There is no option for me to choose to install that management studio. Must i install it seperately?

FYI, i have both sqlserver express 2005 and express 2008 installed. Sqlmanagement studio 2005 is installed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the easiest way to install sql express 2008 w/ management studio is via [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)

I would see if you can add it via that before tracking down individual installers.